# Still "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Tags: node.js, git, npm, webpack, npm-install

Windows 10, Git Bash (as Administator), trying to: `npm install --save-dev webpack-stream` and got this:

```
npm ERR! path D:\Projects\SomeProject\frontend\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Projects\SomeProject\frontend\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\Projects\SomeProject\frontend\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'D:\\Projects\\SomeProject\\frontend\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\getpass\\node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Projects\\SomeProject\\frontend\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\getpass\\node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-05T05_24_31_143Z-debug.log
```

I have trying to:

```
npm cache verify
```

and:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

No results.

Trying turn off antivirus - not results. Trying to run cmd as administrator and then: `cd project-folder -> npm install --save-dev webpack-stream` - no results.

```
npm -v
5.5.1

node -v
v8.9.1
```

Is it possible to resolve my problem?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't, now i install packages like this: npm i *packName*@*previous version* --save. Not best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to click right on the project folder, select "properties", then unselect "Read Only", then "Apply".

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
npm config set unsafe-perm=true
```

[source](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/14)